# When I try to open admin panel it get redirected to woocommerce setup wizard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having very weird issue in my store. I get redirected to woocommerce setup wizard page when I try to open any page in admin panel.

I tried setting up woocommerce settings. I have gone through all the steps and at last I again get redurected to setup wizard.

when I deactivate woocommerce plugin it runs properly. But with woocommerce pplugin it redirects to woo setup wizard.

[image: This screen pops up always as I try to open admin panel]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the tie breaking solution guys. It was like stuck on the same page.
I got a filter from woocommerce docs.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_automatic_wizard_redirect', 'wc_subscriber_auto_redirect', 20, 1 );
function wc_subscriber_auto_redirect( $boolean ) {
    return true;
}
```

This stopped the redirection from admin panel to wc setup wizard.

Answer (score 1):

There is few options why this might happen, but probalby Your browser do cache wp-admin panel url with WOO wizard redirection.

Frist try solution: Delete browser cache.

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment but not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to prevent redirection

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_automatic_wizard_redirect', '__return_true' );`